# Exporting variables between shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have two independently running scripts.
first one lets say script A calculates some values. And i want to echo these values from other script called B. These scripts will not call each other. I have used export keyword but didn't work. How can i do this?

Comment: Will not `. script` do the trick? (see http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-export-environment-variable-from-a-bash-script-344057/)

Comment: @mlvljr You should make this an answer, because it was what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamGriffiths Well, I'm trying to avoid the reputation point race here ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood the requirement then can't both scripts be simply executed in same sub shell, independently but **without** calling each other or without any need of an external file or pipe like this:

Let's say this is your **script1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# script1.sh: do something and finally
export x=19
```

And here us your **script2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# script2.sh: read value of $x here
echo "x="${x}
```

Just call them in same sub-shell like this

```
(. ./script1.sh && ./script2.sh)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
x=19
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 mkfifo /tmp/channel

 process_a.sh > /tmp/channel&
 process_b.sh < /tmp/channel&

 wait
```

Of course you can also just read a single line when you want it.

In bash there are coprocs, which also might be what you want. Random example from [this page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc)

```
# let the output of the coprocess go to stdout
{ coproc mycoproc { awk '{print "foo" $0;fflush()}' ;} >&3 ;} 3>&1
echo bar >&${mycoproc[1]}
foobar
```

ksh has a similar feature, apparently

Comment: communication between separate processes is easiest done with files, and a named pipe provides a handy file-like interface: `A "FIFO" is a special file type that permits independent processes to communicate.`

Comment: coproc is interesting. i'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Think of each script as a function: function A calculates some value and returns it. It does not know who will call it. Function B takes in some value and echo it. It does not care who produced that value.  So, script A is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# a.sh: Calculate something and return the result
echo 19
```

and script B is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# b.sh: Consume the calculated result, which passed in as $1
echo The result is $1
```

Make them executable:

```
chmod +x [ab].sh
```

Now, we can glue them together on the command line:

```
$ b.sh $(a.sh)
The result is 19
```

Semantically, b.sh did not call a.sh. You called a.sh and passed its result to b.sh.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you read a third file, let's say settings.sh with the common exported variables?

```
# common.sh
export MY_PATH=/home/foo/bar/
export VERSION=42.2a
```

and in both A and B `source common.sh` to load those values.

Note that the export may not be required in that case.

Comment: I dont need third file actually.

Answer (score 0):

You may echo values to files, then the other script may read them. If you want to use it as a parameter for something, use reverse aposthrophe:

```
echo `cat storedvalue`
```

Be careful, if the two scripts are running at the same time, concurrency problems may occur, which can cause rarely appearing, mystic-looking errors.

Comment: So how can i pass return value of script A's to the script B?

Answer (score 0):

Actually all your need is `source` you can skip the `export` prefix.

*My use-case was an environment specific settings file, example:*

Within **main_script.sh**

```
THIS_DIR=`dirname $0`
source $THIS_DIR/config_vars.sh
# other commands
```

Within **config_vars.sh**

```
LOCAL_ROOT="$HOME/folder/folder"
REMOTE_USERNAME='someuser'
BACKUP_FOLDER="$LOCAL_ROOT/folder"
# etc.
```